# ActionResult extension doesn't work with Page() ActionResult method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, extension-methods, razor-pages

I have an extension for ActionResult that adds a toast to TempData when returning a page:

```
public static IActionResult WithMessage(this ActionResult result, InformMessage msg)
{
    return new InformMessageResult(result, msg);
}
```

and this is InformMessageResult:

```
public class InformMessageResult : ActionResult
    {
        public ActionResult InnerResult { get; set; }
        public InformMessage InformMessage { get; set; }

        public InformMessageResult (ActionResult innerResult, InformMessage informMsg)
        {
            InnerResult = innerResult;
            InformMessage = informMsg;
        }

        public override async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
        {
            ITempDataDictionaryFactory factory = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ITempDataDictionaryFactory)) as ITempDataDictionaryFactory;
            ITempDataDictionary tempData = factory.GetTempData(context.HttpContext);

            tempData.Put("InformMessage", InformMessage);

            await InnerResult.ExecuteResultAsync(context);
        }
    }
```

This works well with

```
return RedirectToPage(etc).WithMessage(etc)
```

and the like, but fails with

```
return Page().WithMessage(etc)
```

and the debugger highlights

```
await InnerResult.ExecuteResultAsync(context);
```

saying InnerResult not set to an instance of an object.

Is there a way I can make this work with Return Page()?

**Edit for additional info:**

I tested what was being sent in as the "InnerResult" and it looks like with Return Page(), everything is null (by design, I'd say, as I do nothing to it before that point):

with RedirectToPage():

[image]

With Page():

[image]

Comment: Then `InnerResult` is null. verify the type being passed into the result. chances are that it is issue

Comment: I would also suggest, since there is no reason to await anything that you remove the async and just `return InnerResult.ExecuteResultAsync(context);` in the `InformMessageResult `

Comment: @Nkosi -- I added the screenshots of what is being passed in. It looks like it gets a value, but everything in it is null. Is that how Page() usually works?

Comment: It is possible that in the case of `Page()` method, your extension is being executed on the result object before the framework has had time to perform some relevant function on it before execution.

Comment: I have no idea, it's a bit more in the weeds than I'm used to. The only thing I can think of is that Page maybe returns the request that already existed and so the ActionResult getting sent in is null whereas with Redirect, it creates a new request?

Comment: Nah, the result is not null so the issue would be within the `ExecuteResultAsync` called on the inner result

Comment: @Matt Honeycutt - This is your original Alert extension method, do you maybe have an insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Page()` and `RedirectToPage()` are helper methods for `PageResult` and `RedirectToPageResult` respectively. So instead of newing up you call these methods.

When you call `Page()` it calls `ExecuteResultAsync` behind the scenes to render the `PageResult`. At that point, all the properties are null i.e. `Page`, `Model`, `ViewData` etc. As the result is already rendered, So you can't call another `ExecuteResultAsync` using the `WithMessage` extension method.

When you call `RedirectToPage` it issues a 301/302 and generates a new `Request` that will result in `RedirectToPageResult`. So the `RedirectToPageResult` is not rendered yet and you have the option to utilise your `WithMessage` extension method.

Having said that, I don't think it's possible to utilise the `WithMessage` when using `Page()` method, AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

This is an older question, but I needed functionality like this myself, and dug deep to find the reason.

As you can see from your debugging, the `Page` method generates a completely blank `PageResult`. Being as every property is null, calling `ExecuteResultAsync` on it fails as it obviously can't do anything with all-null values.

The reason `Page()` otherwise works the rest of the time is due to behind-the-scenes magic in [PageActionInvoker](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages/Infrastructure/PageActionInvoker.cs), specifically in its InvokeResultAsync method. It will detect that your ViewData and Page are blank and populate them before it, itself, calls the `pageResult.ExecuteResultAsync` method.

Hence, you can still get your `InformMessageResult` to work if you do the same work as PageActionInvoker does. Here's how:

```
public override async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
{
    /* temp data work goes here */

    if (InnerResult is PageResult pageResult)
    {
        var pageContext = context as PageContext
            ?? throw new ArgumentException("context must be a PageContext if your InnerResult is a PageResult.", "context");

        var pageFactoryProvider = pageContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IPageFactoryProvider>();
        var pageFactory = pageFactoryProvider.CreatePageFactory(pageContext.ActionDescriptor);

        var viewContext = new ViewContext(
            pageContext,
            NullView.Instance,
            pageContext.ViewData,
            tempData,
            TextWriter.Null,
            new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.HtmlHelperOptions()
        );
        viewContext.ExecutingFilePath = pageContext.ActionDescriptor.RelativePath;

        pageResult.ViewData = viewContext.ViewData;
        pageResult.Page = (PageBase)pageFactory(pageContext, viewContext);
    }

    await InnerResult.ExecuteResultAsync(context);
}

private class NullView : IView
{
    public static readonly NullView Instance = new NullView();

    public string Path => string.Empty;

    public Task RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Works a treat. Allowed me to get this working with razor pages: https://www.trycatchfail.com/2018/01/22/easily-add-bootstrap-alerts-to-your-viewresults-with-asp-net-core/

Comment: Absolutely what I needed, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem I suspect is that Page() and RedirectToPage() inherit from different base classes.

RedirectToPage() as per this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.redirecttopageresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2). It has the following Inheritance:

> Object -> ActionResult -> RedirectToPageResult

This is exposed by some inheritance of the controller. So you're extension of `ActionResult` is available to be used.

However the Page() method is part of a RazorPages class as per this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.page?view=aspnetcore-2.2). So it's inheritance is as follows:<sup>1</sup>

> Object -> RazorPageBase -> PageBase -> Page

Now the Page() method of that class does return a `PageResult` which looks to inherit from `ActionResult` as [defined here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pageresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

So with that in mind I'd suggest casting it to the base `ActionResult` first, and then using your extension method. Something like this perhaps:

```
var baseClass = (Page() as ActionResult);
return baseClass.WithMessage(etc);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> You can see the base type in the second image the OP supplied.

Comment: I tried that and still get the same error. I tracked it a bit more with a breakpoint and it seems that InnerResult and context both are set to an instance, so I have no idea what it thinks isn't set to an instance of an object. All casting it does is assign all the null stuff to a different ActionResult. It's weird, I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: Have you tried putting a break-point inside of the extension method and seeing if there's anything in there that's being passed through or used that's not set to an instance, i.e. null?